# ROS Hydro Vs Indigo?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS. I have two queries.

Which is the difference between two Hydro or Indigo ?
Which version should I use ?
I observes most of the help and packages are available for Hydro. Does these packages also work for indigo ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191555/ros-hydro-vs-indigo-??/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo is the latest version.  I recommend you use it unless you do have any specific package not available in Indigo. Go for Indigo.

Most of packages` documentation is ready for Indigo as well.
There will always be some leakages in documentation for latest versions.
For specific packages, you can always compile for source .

Look for change log on ros website for exact difference

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2017-03-27**:
Hi, may I ask one question about the indigo and hydro?
so what's the difference between hydro and indigo in ssh configuration? Because when I try to use ssh to remote control the robot, I'm able to control in hydro (same program and configuration) but in Indigo I cannot make it.